# Filtering file-list using grep

Tags: linux, grep

I am trying to list files in a specific directory whose name do not match a certain pattern.
For eg. list all files **not** ending with abc.yml
For this I am using the command:

```
ls | grep -v "*abc.yml"
```

However I still see the files ending with abc.yml, what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Just a guess: are you sure all these letters are in the same encoding? Is it possible that 'a' or 'c' are Cyrillic letters, for example?

Comment: Remove the asterisk. Its meaning is different in regular expressions (that's what grep uses) and glob patterns (that's what the shell uses).

Comment: What you have typed now is a mistake, the previous example with just 'abc.yml' was better, but it can also exclude files with 'abcxyml' in the name, for example

Comment: Thanks @Alex I want to understand why the match with asterisk doesn't work

Comment: Normally * in regex means 'repeat the previous item zero or more times'. For example 'a*' means 'zero or more repetitions of letter a', and '.*' is any number of any characters. But when you start the regex with an asterisk there is no character before it, so it is treated as a normal literal asterisk. so your pattern matches a file name, which has an asterisk followed by abc, followed by any character, followed by yml. (because '.' in regex means any character).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asterisk has a different meaning in regular expressions. In fact, putting it to the front of the expressions makes it match literally. You can remove it, as `grep` tries to match the expression anywhere on the line, it doesn't try to match the whole line. To add the "end of line" anchor, add `$`. Also, `.` matches any character, use `\.` to match a dot literally:

```
ls | grep -v 'abc\.yml$'
```

In some shells, you can use extended globbing to list the files without the need to pipe to grep. For example, in bash:

```
shopt -s extglob
ls !(*abc.yml)
```

Comment: what does putting an Asterisk in front means what is wrong with that ?

Comment: Asterisk at the start of a string matches literally, try `echo 'a*b' | grep '*'`.